# Problems with relative and absolute positioning css

Tags: html, css, position

Below you can see my code. The problem is that section are supposed to be in top right corner. The only way for me to solve the problem is to use relative and absolute positioning, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please help me with finding the solution using absolute and relative positioning.

```html
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jjjj</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;  
        }
        body {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 75px;
            margin-bottom: 75px;
        }
        #test1 {
            position: relative;
        }
        #test2 {
            position: relative;
        }
        #test3 {
            position: relative;
        }
        .base {
            background-color: #979691;
            border: black solid 2px;
            margin: 15px;  
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .row {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #p1 {
            background-color: #D789B9;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 110;
        }
        #p2 {
            background-color: #D51537;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        #p3 {
            background-color: #D8C84F;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .col-lg-4, .right-top-lg {
                float: left;
            }
            .col-lg-4{
                width: 33%;
            }
            .right-top-lg {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 100px;
                left: 0px;
                font-weight: 400;
                border: black solid 2px;
                width: 100px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
            .col-md-6, .col-md-12, .right-top-md{
                float: left;
            }
            .col-md-6{
                width: 50%;
            }
            .col-md-12{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 767px) {
             .col-sm-12, .right-top-sm {
                float: left;
            }
            .col-sm-12{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head> 

    <h1>
        Our Menu
    </h1>
    <div  class="row">
        <div id="test1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <p id="p1" class="right-top-lg">Chiken</p>
            <p class="base">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <p id="p2" class="right-top-lg">Beef</p>
            <p class="base">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <p id="p3" class="right-top-lg">Sushi</p>
            <p class="base">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code into a Code snippet (CTRL + M on Windows and CMD + M on mac)

Comment: Put your HTML Code

Comment: I added html code, sorry for long respond im new to this site and programming.

Comment: Could you clarify what is code snippet please.

Comment: @monkey There is an icon above the textarea input that looks like a page with angle brackets `<>`.  click on that and paste in your code.  When submitted, this will allow the code to be rendered by a user to see what the actual issue is.

Comment: @Laisender
 Did it.

Comment: Close enough, but it would be the best to create the snippet that can be rendered.  If my edit gets approved, you will see what I mean.

Comment: @PsiKai did it right?

Answer (score 0):

The position elements were working exactly as you wrote it, but the problem was that you put a margin on the `p` element that was supposed to look like the container.  So the corner label appeared to break out of the box, when in fact it was sitting right where you wanted it to relative to it's parent container.

2 possible solutions.

1. move the `margin: 15px;` to the parent containers (`#test1` etc)
2. Put the background color and border on the parent containers so it doesn't appear to break out

Here is option 1.

```html
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jjjj</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;  
        }
        body {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 75px;
            margin-bottom: 75px;
        }
        #test1 {
            position: relative;
            margin: 15px;  
        }
        #test2 {
            position: relative;
            margin: 15px;  
        }
        #test3 {
            position: relative;
            margin: 15px;  
        }
        .base {
            background-color: #979691;
            border: black solid 2px;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .row {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #p1 {
            background-color: #D789B9;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 110;
        }
        #p2 {
            background-color: #D51537;
            color: white;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        #p3 {
            background-color: #D8C84F;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 600;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .col-lg-4, .right-top-lg {
                float: left;
            }
            .col-lg-4{
                width: 33%;
            }
            .right-top-lg {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 100px;
                left: 0px;
                font-weight: 400;
                border: black solid 2px;
                width: 100px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
            .col-md-6, .col-md-12, .right-top-md{
                float: left;
            }
            .col-md-6{
                width: 50%;
            }
            .col-md-12{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 767px) {
             .col-sm-12, .right-top-sm {
                float: left;
            }
            .col-sm-12{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head> 

    <h1>
        Our Menu
    </h1>
    <div  class="row">
        <div id="test1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <p id="p1" class="right-top-lg">Chiken</p>
            <p class="base">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <p id="p2" class="right-top-lg">Beef</p>
            <p class="base">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <p id="p3" class="right-top-lg">Sushi</p>
            <p class="base">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you explain 2 solution?